# Overflow error when ordering columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that orders some columns based on their name. It worked on a file with less columns ~(30) but it now renders Overflow error with ~75 columns. (I should note that there are several columns named "#", I placed the '#' at the end of the array so the macro leaves all columns with '#' at the end and then I delete them later). Here's the code:

```
Sub reorder_columns()

'Purpose: reorder the columns into the appropiate file order

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim Temp
Dim nams As Variant
Dim F
Dim Dex As Integer

nams = Array("PO Number", "PO Line Number", "Vendor’s ID", "Reseller Name","etc","#")
Set rng = Sheets("output").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    For J = i To rng.Columns.Count
        For F = 0 To UBound(nams)
            If nams(F) = rng(J) Then Dex = F: Exit For
        Next F
        If F < i Then

'***overflow comes in next line*******************
        Temp = rng.Columns(i).Value

        rng(i).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = rng.Columns(J).Value
        rng(J).Resize(rng.Rows.Count) = Temp
    End If
   Next J
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you looping `rng.Columns.Count` within `rng.Columns.Count`?  ...and why `CurrentrRegion`?  (You should probably Google the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-currentregion-property-excel) for properties you use that might that you aren't familiar with.)  Also, figure out how many loops you're doing and that will probably answer your question

Comment: ...also, you know which line is giving the overflow error.  Which data type have you set for the variable on that line?

Comment: ...also, Excel has built-in sort functionality.  I'm not clear on what you're trying to do here but if the built-in functionality isn't usable for your purposes then I'd suggest you use one of the many [existing sort procedures](https://www.google.ca/search?q=vba+sort+algoritms).

Comment: I detailed which line gives the overflow error. I use this macro in this way because I need it to replicate this on several files with different specs.